# How to add the key of the object to the array in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have such objects:

```
robot {
  id
  skill
  currentWorkPlace
}

warehouse {
  aiStaff
  currentStatus
  boxes
}
```

I have to write a function that should add the id of a new worker to the aiStaff array, and write a reference to the warehouse object to the job in the currentWorkPlace. But I don't know how not to change the array in the warehouse.('registerRobot' function should not rewrite array 'aiStaff' inside 'warehouse' object) and I don't have to create a new variable

There is my code:

```
function registerRobot(robot, warehouse) {
  robot.currentWorkPlace = warehouse;
  robot.currentWorkPlace.aiStaff = [robot.id];
}
```

I dont know how to not rewrite array 'aiStaff'. Please help me Guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your `warehouse.aiStaff` is an array. In this case change your function to add the robot ID to the array:

```
function registerRobot(robot, warehouse) {
  robot.currentWorkPlace = warehouse;
  robot.currentWorkPlace.aiStaff.push(robot.id);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought about it but for some reason, I didn't try it

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you need to 'add' a new robot, but you are having the issue that the entire array gets overridden.

Considering `warehouse.aiStaff` is an array, if you want to add a new 'worker' you need to `push` the new item into the array.

```js
function registerRobot(robot, warehouse) {
  robot.currentWorkPlace = warehouse;
  robot.currentWorkPlace.aiStaff.push({
    id: robot.id
  });
}
```